# Draw snakes on a grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

My question is quite simple: how can I draw a "snake" line sitting on a grid?

To be more specific, refer to the upload image, but there are important differences: I'd like the curved connecting lines to be **circles**, and I think the right approach would be that the outgoing tangent to be 45 degrees, and the ingoing one -135 degrees.

My code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[darkstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!20}]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6}
        \foreach \y in {0,...,3} 
        {
            \node [darkstyle]  (\x, \y) at (\x, \y)
            { };
        } 
    \draw (0, 0)--(3, 3) to[out=45, in=-135] (4, 3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I have an error:

```
./main.tex:57: Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgf@ya 

l.57 ...w (0, 0)--(3, 3) to[out=45, in=-135] (4, 3)
                                                  ;
```

I don't understand why I am having this error.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

[image: snake line]

Comment: For the loop instruction, simply use `\node [darkstyle]  at (\x, \y) {};`

Comment: Does something like `\draw (0, 0) -- (3, 3) .. controls +(45:1.4) and +(45:1.4) .. (4, 3);` work?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edited per request for arrow tips

### The output

The cutest version first, with styling :

```
\draw [serpent,-{Arc Barb[reversed,length=15pt,width=25pt]}] (1, 1)
```

gives :

[image]

or the version below :

[image: ![enter image description here]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
 \tikzset
 {
   darkstyle/.style=
   {
     circle,draw,fill=gray!20
   },
   serpent/.style =
  {
    line join = round,
    line width=9pt,
    line cap=round,
    red,
    %opacity=.7, % see below
  },
 }

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,7}
  {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,4} 
    {
      \node[darkstyle]  at (\x, \y) {};
    } 
  }
  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=0.70] %for correct transparency of arrow tips
    \draw [serpent,-{Triangle Cap []. Fast Triangle[] Fast Triangle[]}] (1, 1)
    foreach \k in {1,2}
    {
      -- (3+2*\k,5) arc [radius = .25 * sqrt(2), start angle = 135, delta angle = -180]  
      -- (2*\k-1,0) arc [radius = .25 * sqrt(2), start angle = 135, delta angle = 180]
    }
    -- (6.8,2.8) ;
    ;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Beautiful! Is it possible to add an arrow at the end of the serpent line?

Comment: @senseiwa Sure ! just add `->` to the `\draw` options, or perhaps another arrow tip.